# How to change Model name to leverage different property in Forge Viewer

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a .stp file that has random integer name values for model names in the Model Browser but a valid (ie. human readable) Component Name. I would like to replace the default name with the Component Name in the Model Browser for these cases.

I've looked at a couple similar posts on SO but nothing has worked for me as yet ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652819/how-to-change-object-names-in-forge-viewer) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54949479/can-i-change-text-contents-in-the-viewer/54966633#54966633)). I'm using version 6.3.1 of the viewer.

In my investigation into where the data is stored, I've found a strings array in the InstanceTree as well as a PropDbLoader (in the ViewerPropertyPanel). The strings array seems to get populated with the name data (in an interesting ASCII array look-up setup) and the PropDbLoader has properties for the models. The name for the model in the Model Browser popup looks to come from within the ModelStructureTreeDelegate class (InstanceTree.getNodeName). I'd like to be able to extend or override the getNodeName and populate it with Component Name but I have (as of yet) not found a way to get at this data in the model tree.

Any insight or direction would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will need to extend/override the default DIV creation behaviour for model tree nodes here and customize to your needs:

```
ModelStructureTreeDelegate.prototype.createTreeNode
```

[image]
See [here](https://github.com/yiskang/forge-au-sample/tree/master/model-structure) for code sample.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I took a look at the code and while there is some useful stuff there I'm still having trouble finding a way to get at the properties of the actual selected model. Do you know of a way to leverage the id here to get at it's properties (specifically Component Name) - either in the propDbLoader or some other location?

Comment: Try [viewer.getProperties](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D.html#getProperties) and [viewer.getSelection](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D.html#getSelection) to obtain the dbids of selected components.